# How do I ensure a program I'm starting writes its stdout to a FD I opened?

Tags: c, io-redirection

I am trying to implement the `>` and `<` redirection for my shell but in my case, let's say I do `ls > output.txt`, it creates a new file but wouldn't write it in the file. Here's a preview of my code:

```
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){
        int i = 0;
        for (i=0; args[i]!='\0'; i++){
            int fd;
            if (strcmp(args[i], ">")==0){

                fd = open(args[i+1], O_CREAT|O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0600);
                dup2(fd,  STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(fd);

            }
            if(strcmp(args[i], "<")==0){

                fd = open(args[i+1],O_RDONLY);
                dup2(fd,  STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(fd);
            }
```

Comment: What happens instead? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: The question doesn't show how/where you're `exec`ing the replacement process, so we can't see what the FD table active at the time of its invocation would be. Please note the [mcve] guidelines: The code in a question should be the shortest possible (*minimal*) thing that's both *complete* and *verifiable* -- meaning someone can copy-and-paste it, run it themselves without any other changes, and reproduce your problem or test their proposed fix.

Comment: Also, this shouldn't be tagged `shell` at all -- it's not a question about how to write programs in shell languages; it's a question about writing software in C, and should be tagged as such.

Comment: Are you by chance testing < and > together? Because < is also using `dup2()` to overwrite `STDOUT_FILENO` which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: *nod*; `<` should be `STDIN_FILENO`. Not that that explains why `>` isn't working, but the question doesn't contain enough details to determine that regardless.

Comment: I apologize for using the wrong tag, let me try fixing the STDIN and STDOUT

Comment: Do check the return values of your function calls to make sure they have succeeded, and to take appropriate action in the event that they fail.  I doubt that your issue arises from a failure in one of the function calls shown, but who's to say?  Nobody knows, not even you, if you don't check.

Comment: I changed the STDIN and STDOUT for >  and < accordingly and it still wouldn't add anything to the output file

Comment: Yes -- as I said, we can't debug this without seeing the `exec` call as well (not to mention being aware of any failed function calls, as JohnBollinger points out). Please [edit] the code to be a proper [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Try this >> instead of >

'>>' append at end of file

Comment: I need to implement that as well along with > and < but how do I fix these?

Comment: This has *nothing whatsoever* to do with the OP's question. How is anyone upvoting it?